# Showing a 'Now Playing' in HTML and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, spotify

I have been trying to use some PHP and HTML code (with a bit of js) to create a 'now playing' spotify viewer for my website. I just cannot get it working. I have tried all the possibilities such as renaming files, changing the HTML and PHP and JS versions but nothing seems to work. Below is my HTML code (js) and PHP code.

```
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!--Begin Spotify Scrobble-->
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">function get_spotify() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/public_html/Spotify.php',
        data: { request: 'true' },
        success: function(reply) {
            $('.now-playing').html("<p>" + reply + "</p>");
        }
    });
}
</script>
<!--End Spotify Scrobble-->
```

PHP

```
?php
// Account & API Account Information
$user = "USERNAME"; // <---- Your username goes here
$key = "KEY"; //<-- Your API key goes here

 +
  // The URL of the request to API Service
  $url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?              method=user.getrecenttracks&user=USERNAME&api_key=APIKEY&forma    t=json";
 +
  // Enable Shortening
  $short_titles = false;
 +
 // Setup cURL for request
  $ch = curl_init( $url );
 -// Options for cURL
  $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        );
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
 -// Execute cURL and save return to $json
 +
 +// Execute cURL
  $json = curl_exec($ch);
 -// Close the connection
  curl_close($ch);
 -// Decode JSON response to array.
  $data = json_decode($json,true);
 +
  // Get only the latest track information
  $last = $data['recenttracks']['track'][0];
 +
  // Is now playing attribute present?
  if (isset($last['@attr']['nowplaying'])) {
-      // Echo now playing information.
 +
        $output = "I am currently listening to " . $last['name'] . ' by ' .     $last['artist']['#text'] . " on Spotify.";
 +
        if ($short_titles) {
                $output = sTrim($output);
        }
 +
        echo trim($output);
  } else {
 -      // Collect info on when this was last played and get the current UNIX time.
        $played = $last['date']['uts']; $now = time();
 -      // Get the difference
        $diff = abs($now - $played);
-      // format hours
 +
 +      // Time formatting
        $hours = intval(intval($diff) / 3600); 
 -      // format minutes
        $minutes = intval(($diff / 60) % 60);
 -      // IF hours is empty(equal to zero) 
 +
 +      // String formatting based on time
        if (!empty($hours)) {
 -              if ($hours > 24) // Is it more than 1 day?
 +              if ($hours > 24)
                        $time = "over a day ago";
                else
                        $time = $hours . " hours and " . $minutes . " minutes ago";
        } else
                $time = $minutes . " minutes ago";
 +
        $output = "I last listened to " . $last['name'] . ' by ' . $last['artist']    ['#text'] . " $time on Spotify";
 +
        if ($short_titles) {
                $output = sTrim($output);
        }
 +
        echo trim($output);
  }
 +
  exit();

  function sTrim($output) {
```

Comment: Why cannot you get it work? Is there an error? Little details help us solve your problems accurately

Comment: There is 1 error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/a1825511/public_html/Spotify.php on line 33 but that only just started showing up. Before it just gave me my standard webpage without the spotify plugin showing

Comment: Alright. That isn't a JS issue. Also key your credentials out of the post

Comment: Can you post the code for spotify.php, without the diff text?